# How can I get the window object that an HTML node belongs to using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xul, xulrunner

Because of several iframes, XUL browser elements, and so forth, I have a number of window objects in my XULRunner application. I'm looking for the best way to find the window object that a specified node belongs to using JavaScript.

So, to be more specific, given node x, I need to find the specific window object that contains x.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

+1 to your question, it was exactly what I was looking for and thanks for the hint given directly by answering yourself.

I Googled a bit and according to http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html cross-browsers tables I think the right answer is:

```
function GetOwnerWindow(html_node)
{
   /*
   ownerDocument is cross-browser, 
   but defaultView works on all browsers except Opera/IE that use parentWinow
   */
   return (html_node.ownerDocument.defaultView) ?
      html_node.ownerDocument.defaultView : 
      html_node.ownerDocument.parentWindow;
}
```

Or maybe even better:

```
return html_node.ownerDocument.defaultView || html_node.ownerDocument.parentWindow;
```

Plz let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use **self**.  self is a reference to the current document.

**From within the iframe:**

```
<body>
<div id="example">Example!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var exampleNode = document.getElementById('example');
        exampleNode.bar = function () {
            // The highest window object:
            top;
            // The parent node:
            self;
            // The parent node ( except in IE );
            this.ownerDocument.defaultView;
        };
    };
</script>
</body>
```

**Traversing Multiple Window Objects:**

Within the browser object model, the primary window object is referred to as **top**.  Other global objects are arranged in a tree structure which stems from top.  With a reference to **top**, you can navigate to the other global objects in the tree by using their **names and relationships**, much in the same way as you **traverse the DOM**.

When you have multiple window objects, as you do in the case of an iframe (of with old school framesets), the frame has a **name attribute**.  Given the objects position relative to the top window object, you can use the name of the child to access the object.

`<iframe src ="/default.html" name="advertisement"></iframe>`

and then from the context of the top window:

`self.advertisement`

Answer (score 3):

I found the combination of properties I was after:

node.ownerDocument.defaultView

That returns the window object that the node belongs to. Note that this does not work in IE.

Comment: node.ownerDocument.defaultView is the standard way to do it. That will work on web pages in Safari and Opera too.