# How do you check if a JavaScript Object is a DOM Object?

Tags: javascript, dom, object

I'm trying to get:

```
document.createElement('div')  //=> true
{tagName: 'foobar something'}  //=> false
```

In my own scripts, I used to just use this since I never needed `tagName` as a property:

```
if (!object.tagName) throw ...;
```

So for the second object, I came up with the following as a quick solution -- which mostly works. ;)

The problem is, it depends on browsers enforcing read-only properties, which not all do.

```
function isDOM(obj) {
  var tag = obj.tagName;
  try {
    obj.tagName = '';  // Read-only for DOM, should throw exception
    obj.tagName = tag; // Restore for normal objects
    return false;
  } catch (e) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Is there a good substitute?

Comment: Am I being obtuse in wondering whether a "DOM Object" shouldn't cover not only Elements but also all Nodes (Text nodes, Attributes, etc.)?  All the answers and the way you've posed the question tend to suggest this question is specifically about Elements...

Answer (score 357, accepted):

This might be of interest:

```
function isElement(obj) {
  try {
    //Using W3 DOM2 (works for FF, Opera and Chrome)
    return obj instanceof HTMLElement;
  }
  catch(e){
    //Browsers not supporting W3 DOM2 don't have HTMLElement and
    //an exception is thrown and we end up here. Testing some
    //properties that all elements have (works on IE7)
    return (typeof obj==="object") &&
      (obj.nodeType===1) && (typeof obj.style === "object") &&
      (typeof obj.ownerDocument ==="object");
  }
}
```

It's part of the [DOM, Level2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html).

**Update 2**: This is how I implemented it in my own library:
(the previous code didn't work in Chrome, because Node and HTMLElement are functions instead of the expected object. This code is tested in FF3, IE7, Chrome 1 and Opera 9).

```
//Returns true if it is a DOM node
function isNode(o){
  return (
    typeof Node === "object" ? o instanceof Node : 
    o && typeof o === "object" && typeof o.nodeType === "number" && typeof o.nodeName==="string"
  );
}

//Returns true if it is a DOM element    
function isElement(o){
  return (
    typeof HTMLElement === "object" ? o instanceof HTMLElement : //DOM2
    o && typeof o === "object" && o !== null && o.nodeType === 1 && typeof o.nodeName==="string"
);
}
```

Comment: The non W3 DOM2 should probably be return (typeof obj==="object") && (obj.nodeType===1) && (typeof obj.tagName==="string"); to work in all browsers.

Comment: It's worth noting that this will not work on elements that belong to other windows/frames.  Duck typing is the recommended approach

Comment: You can fool it with: `function Fake() {}; Fake.prototype=document.createElement("div"); alert(new Fake() instanceof HTMLElement);`

Comment: WTF fact: Firefox 5 and earlier return `true` for `[] instanceof HTMLElement`.

Comment: Btw, `HTMLElement` is always a `function`, so `typeof` will throw you off the track and will execute the second part of the statement. You could try if you wish `instanceof Object`, because the function will be an instance of `Object`, or just check explicitly for `typeof === "function"`, because `Node` and `HTMLElement` are both native object functions.

Comment: `typeof HTMLElement === "object"` in IE10 and `typeof HTMLElement === "function"` in Chrome for example. So one should test `typeof HTMLElement` for either "object" or "function" before usage of `o instanceof HTMLElement`

Comment: @some your `isElement` function returns `undefined` when `o` is `undefined`. You should add `!!` after the `return` and before the opening bracket.

Comment: This answer does not work for SVG elements. Also, not many people care about DOM2 support anymore; See my answer (supported back to IE7) below if you care about SVG elements but not DOM2.

Comment: **Important**: Please note, when checking this against an iframe it won't work in Chrome. You'll explicitely have to check against inside the iframe context, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26251098/3894981)!

Comment: When you call `isElement(0)`, it returns 0, not false... Why is that, and how can I prevent that?

Comment: @Jessica Use !!o to prevent && short circuiting. Which also removes the need for a check of o !== null.

Comment: I don't understand the complexity... but must admit I didn't test this cross-browser... but anyway here's my take which is based on the assumption that `HTMLElement` never changes, so it it's here once it's here always - so check it once... AND that HTMLElement being object or function, I don't care... just don't be `undefined`. CODE --->

`const isHTMLElement = typeof HTMLElement !== 'undefined'
  ? obj => obj instanceof HTMLElement
  : obj => typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null && obj.nodeType === 1 && typeof obj.nodeName === 'string'
;`

Comment: Rly, when it a Node, we'll break it in the pure js append method?

Answer (score 116):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384380/1204556) is a bit complicated, and does not detect all types of HTML elements. For example, SVG elements are not supported. In contrast, this answer works for HTML as well as SVG, etc.

See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/eLuhbu6r/

```
function isElement(element) {
    return element instanceof Element || element instanceof HTMLDocument;  
}
```

Cherry on top: the above code is IE8 compatible.

Comment: 'Element' is undefined on IE7

Comment: I'm of the opinion that anyone still using IE7 should spend the five seconds to download a better browser instead of putting it on us to invest days or weeks working around their refusal to get with the times.

Comment: I do agree with @mopsyd, but the author of the answer states, that it works in IE7, which might need to be updated for the sake of correctness.

Comment: Updated to say IE9. I'm unsure if IE8 supports it.

Comment: @MonarchWadia yes it is supported in IE8. But note that this does not return true for `document` element (in all browsers). if you need it, you should try: `x instanceof Element || x instanceof HTMLDocument`

Comment: changed as per your comments

Comment: I am of the opinion that anyone using browsers older than say about five years from the current standard are not worth rendering to. If your client is an old browser you're probably using an older computer or mobile device which means you're less likely to spend. After all rendering is mostly about paying customers.

Comment: Note that this does not work across multiple windows. I.e. `window.open().document.body instanceof Element` returns `false`.

Comment: @nik10110 You're checking if the NEW window's `body` instance is an instance of the OLD window's `Element`. It works if you adjust your code as below :-)
`win = window.open(); win.document.body instanceof win.Element; // true`

Comment: @mopsyd: I.T. departments, and clients, sometimes have restrictions on which browser(s) can be used.

Comment: I can appreciate that there are restrictions to a point. However the point of such restrictions is to limit security liabilities. At this point restricting to IE7 for the sake of security is like trying to put a deadbolt lock on a door that is a tarp flap.

Comment: `HTMLDocument` is deprecated. MDN says that `HTMLDocument` might be considered as an alias for `Document`, so the condition could be written like `element instanceof Element || element instanceof Document`.

Comment: + use `Document` instead of `HTMLDocument` as it's marked as depricated,

Answer (score 49):

No need for hacks, you can just ask if an element is an instance of the DOM [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element):

```
const isDOM = el => el instanceof Element
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works!

Comment: Has almost complete compatibility (https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_instanceof), this should be the accepted answer

Comment: A side note: If anyone will use this also to check if the element is still a part of a DOM (which kinda this question evokes), then this check fails. It only checks type of the element, not its real existence.

Comment: almost perfect, except does not work on event.target

Comment: @AiShiguang Why would it not work on `event.target`? The [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/target) isn’t always an Element, but `instanceof` is unrelated to the specifics of how events work.

Comment: You're right, and that's exactly why I would test if a target were an Element. And it does not work since it's always false, no matter if it is actually an Element or isn't.

Comment: @AiShiguang `addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => console.log(target, target instanceof Element));` always reports the element (`<input>`, `<div>`, `<body>`, `<html>`) and `true`, in the latest Firefox and Chrome. There’s no reason why it wouldn’t. What value of `target` are you seeing instead? What browser are you using?

Comment: Aww~ my bad. Mine was in an iframe. therefore it's not window.Element

Comment: I love this simple and working solution!

Answer (score 12):

All solutions above and below (my solution including) suffer from possibility of being incorrect, especially on IE — it is quite possible to (re)define some objects/methods/properties to mimic a DOM node rendering the test invalid.

So usually I use the duck-typing-style testing: I test specifically for things I use. For example, if I want to clone a node I test it like this:

```
if(typeof node == "object" && "nodeType" in node &&
   node.nodeType === 1 && node.cloneNode){
  // most probably this is a DOM node, we can clone it safely
  clonedNode = node.cloneNode(false);
}
```

Basically it is a little sanity check + the direct test for a method (or a property) I am planning to use.

Incidentally the test above is a good test for DOM nodes on all browsers. But if you want to be on the safe side always check the presence of methods and properties and verify their types.

**EDIT:** IE uses ActiveX objects to represent nodes, so their properties do not behave as true JavaScript object, for example:

```
console.log(typeof node.cloneNode);              // object
console.log(node.cloneNode instanceof Function); // false
```

while it should return "function" and `true` respectively. The only way to test methods is to see if the are defined.

Comment: "typeof document.body.cloneNode" does return "object" in my IE

Comment: This looks like a decent answer. See my answer below though,  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36894871/1204556

Answer (score 10):

A simple way to test if a variable is a DOM element (verbose, but more traditional syntax :-)

```
function isDomEntity(entity) {
  if(typeof entity  === 'object' && entity.nodeType !== undefined){
     return true;
  }
  else{
     return false;
  }
}
```

Or as [HTMLGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521341/htmlguy) suggested (short and clean syntax):

```
const isDomEntity = entity =>
  typeof entity === 'object' && entity.nodeType !== undefined
```

Comment: Way too verbose. The comparison will already return a boolean:
`return typeof entity === 'object' && typeof entity.nodeType !== undefined;`

Comment: Very interesting! Sometimes, depending on the Types you have on your `object`s and/or poperties, this can be very handy!  Tx, @Roman

Comment: Ironically, because `null` is an _"object",_ you'll see: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'entity.nodeType')`

Answer (score 9):

You could try appending it to a real DOM node...

```
function isDom(obj)
{
    var elm = document.createElement('div');
    try
    {
        elm.appendChild(obj);
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Does this work?  It's still a solution.  A creative one at that.

Comment: +1 for the creativity and certainty this offers. However, if the node happens to be part of the DOM already, you've just removed it! So ... this answer is incomplete without doing the work to re-add the element to the DOM if necessary.

Comment: I'm reading this after almost 5 years, and I think it's one of the coolest. It just needs to be refined. You can try to append a *clone* of the node to a detached element, for example. If that's not a DOM object. something will surely go wrong. Still quite an expensive solution, though.

Comment: Or instead of trying to append the *clone* of the element, *just trying to clone it* should be enough: `obj.cloneNode(false)`. **AND** has no side effects.

Comment: This is really expensive and unnecessarily complicated. See my answer below, http://stackoverflow.com/a/36894871/1204556

Comment: It's creative and would be fine except it has the horrible side-effect of altering the object that you are testing! I.e. it potentially removes the valid DOM element from it's current parent! @Greg should alter the answer to mention this explicitly as it is dangerous to use as-is.

Answer (score 8):

How about [Lo-Dash's `_.isElement`](https://lodash.com/docs#isElement)?

```
$ npm install lodash.iselement
```

And in the code:

```
var isElement = require("lodash.iselement");
isElement(document.body);
```

Comment: I like this solution. It is simple, and it works in Edge and IE, even for elements in separate iframes, unlike most of the highest voted solutions here.

Comment: This answer is helpful, though one would need Webpack to run NPM modules in the browser.

Answer (score 6):

This is from the lovely JavaScript library [MooTools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MooTools):

```
if (obj.nodeName){
    switch (obj.nodeType){
    case 1: return 'element';
    case 3: return (/\S/).test(obj.nodeValue) ? 'textnode' : 'whitespace';
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't assert that the object is a DOM element; only that it looks a little bit like one.  Any object can be given a nodeName and nodeType property and satisfy this code.

Comment: This answer does not detect all types of HTML elements. For example, SVG elements are not supported. See my answer below.

Comment: Doesn't really work on all elements, for example SVG. See my answer below, http://stackoverflow.com/a/36894871/1204556

Answer (score 4):

old thread, but here's an updated possibility for **ie8 and ff3.5** users:

```
function isHTMLElement(o) {
    return (o.constructor.toString().search(/\object HTML.+Element/) > -1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The using the root detection found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223991/how-can-i-get-the-window-object-that-an-html-node-belongs-to-using-javascript), we can determine whether e.g. *alert* is a member of the object's root, which is then likely to be a window:

```
function isInAnyDOM(o) { 
  return (o !== null) && !!(o.ownerDocument && (o.ownerDocument.defaultView || o.ownerDocument.parentWindow).alert); // true|false
}
```

To determine whether the object is the current window is even simpler:

```
function isInCurrentDOM(o) { 
  return (o !== null) && !!o.ownerDocument && (window === (o.ownerDocument.defaultView || o.ownerDocument.parentWindow)); // true|false
}
```

This seems to be less expensive than the try/catch solution in the opening thread.

Don P

Comment: I've tested this in latest Chrome and FF, and also in IE11, and it works everywhere, also for text nodes and objects created via `document.createElement()` but not inserted in DOM too.  Amazing (: Thank you

Comment: This looks like a decent answer, though mine does a lot of the same stuff and is less complicated. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36894871/1204556

Answer (score 3):

```
var IsPlainObject = function ( obj ) { return obj instanceof Object && ! ( obj instanceof Function || obj.toString( ) !== '[object Object]' || obj.constructor.name !== 'Object' ); },
    IsDOMObject = function ( obj ) { return obj instanceof EventTarget; },
    IsDOMElement = function ( obj ) { return obj instanceof Node; },
    IsListObject = function ( obj ) { return obj instanceof Array || obj instanceof NodeList; },
```

// In fact I am more likely t use these inline, but sometimes it is good to have these shortcuts for setup code

Comment: obj.constructor.name doesn't work in IE, because in IE, functions do not have the name property. Replace by obj.constructor != Object.

Answer (score 3):

This could be helpful: **[isDOM](http://jherax.github.io/#isdom-object)**

```
//-----------------------------------
// Determines if the @obj parameter is a DOM element
function isDOM (obj) {
    // DOM, Level2
    if ("HTMLElement" in window) {
        return (obj && obj instanceof HTMLElement);
    }
    // Older browsers
    return !!(obj && typeof obj === "object" && obj.nodeType === 1 && obj.nodeName);
}
```

In the code above, we use the **double negation** operator to get the boolean value of the object passed as argument, this way we ensure that each expression evaluated in the conditional statement be boolean, taking advantage of the **[Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation)**, thus the function returns `true` or `false`

Comment: Anything falsy should short-circuit your boolean. `undefined && window.spam("should bork")` never evaluates the fake `spam` function, for instance. So no `!!` needed, I don't believe. That, can you provide a [non-academic] edge case where its use matters?

Comment: Thank you for your aclaration. I used _*!!* double negation_ to convert all expression to boolean value, not truthy or falsy.

Comment: Right, but there's no practical reason to do it, I don't think -- see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript/29951409#29951409). And it's certainly not necessary to take advantage of Short-Cut eval here. Even if you didn't buy the "`!!` is never needed" argument (**and if you don't, I'm curious why not**), you could edit that line to `return !!(obj && typeof obj === "object" && obj.nodeType === 1 && obj.nodeName);` and have it operate the same.

Comment: That was what I did ;) more clean and same effect. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think prototyping is not a very good solution but maybe this is the fastest one:
Define this code block;

```
Element.prototype.isDomElement = true;
HTMLElement.prototype.isDomElement = true;
```

than check your objects isDomElement property:

```
if(a.isDomElement){}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: 1) changing objects you don't own is not advisable. 2) this doesn't detect elements that aren't not part of the same document.

Comment: this will still not be detected
```js
var fake = Object.create(Element.prototype)
```

Comment: First, what we're trying to do on another document which we don't have any control on it? Second, why we're creating a fake object from Element instead of document.createElement? I didn't understand the use cases here.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you have to do is make a thorough check of some properties that will always be in a dom element, but their combination won't *most likely* be in another object, like so:

```
var isDom = function (inp) {
    return inp && inp.tagName && inp.nodeName && inp.ownerDocument && inp.removeAttribute;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)

> `Element` is the most general base class from which all objects in a `Document` inherit. It only has methods and properties common to all kinds of elements.

We can implement `isElement` by prototype. Here is my advice:

```js
/**
 * @description detect if obj is an element
 * @param {*} obj
 * @returns {Boolean}
 * @example
 * see below
 */
function isElement(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
    return false
  }
  let prototypeStr, prototype
  do {
    prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)
    // to work in iframe
    prototypeStr = Object.prototype.toString.call(prototype)
    // '[object Document]' is used to detect document
    if (
      prototypeStr === '[object Element]' ||
      prototypeStr === '[object Document]'
    ) {
      return true
    }
    obj = prototype
    // null is the terminal of object
  } while (prototype !== null)
  return false
}
console.log(isElement(document)) // true
console.log(isElement(document.documentElement)) // true
console.log(isElement(document.body)) // true
console.log(isElement(document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0])) // true or false, decided by whether there is svg element
console.log(isElement(document.getElementsByTagName('svg'))) // false
console.log(isElement(document.createDocumentFragment())) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, you can use the `instanceof Node`. That `Node` is defined in [DOM1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-core.html#ID-1950641247).

But that is not that easy in IE.

1. "instanceof ActiveXObject" only can tell that it is a native object.
2. "typeof document.body.appendChild=='object'" tell that it may be DOM object, but also can be something else have same function.

You can only ensure it is DOM element by using DOM function and catch if any exception. However, it may have side effect (e.g. change object internal state/performance/memory leak)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is an alternative? Tested in Opera 11, FireFox 6, Internet Explorer 8, Safari 5 and Google Chrome 16.

```
function isDOMNode(v) {
  if ( v===null ) return false;
  if ( typeof v!=='object' ) return false;
  if ( !('nodeName' in v) ) return false; 

  var nn = v.nodeName;
  try {
    // DOM node property nodeName is readonly.
    // Most browsers throws an error...
    v.nodeName = 'is readonly?';
  } catch (e) {
    // ... indicating v is a DOM node ...
    return true;
  }
  // ...but others silently ignore the attempt to set the nodeName.
  if ( v.nodeName===nn ) return true;
  // Property nodeName set (and reset) - v is not a DOM node.
  v.nodeName = nn;

  return false;
}
```

Function won't be fooled by e.g. this

```
isDOMNode( {'nodeName':'fake'} ); // returns false
```

Comment: Good try, but exception handling is too expensive a cost if it can be avoided.  Also, ES5 allows you to define read-only properties for objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can see if the object or node in question returns a string type.

```
typeof (array).innerHTML === "string" => false
typeof (object).innerHTML === "string" => false
typeof (number).innerHTML === "string" => false
typeof (text).innerHTML === "string" => false

//any DOM element will test as true
typeof (HTML object).innerHTML === "string" => true
typeof (document.createElement('anything')).innerHTML === "string" => true
```

Comment: `typeof ({innerHTML: ""}).innerHTML === "string"`

Comment: HOT! This response should be the game winner. if(typeof obj.innerHTML!=='string') //not a dom element.

Comment: I initially reacted against @Qtax 's and [thomasrutter's critique on an earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384286/javascript-isdom-how-do-you-check-if-a-javascript-object-is-a-dom-object#comment9376470_384301), but I'm starting to buy it. Though I haven't run into dogs quacking like ducks exactly like this before, I can see someone not checking if something's a node, running `notANode.innerHTML = "<b>Whoops</b>";`, then later having that code pass its contaminated obj to *this* code. Defensive code === better code, all other things equal, and this ultimately isn't defensive.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I figured out:

```
var isHTMLElement = (function () {
    if ("HTMLElement" in window) {
        // Voilà. Quick and easy. And reliable.
        return function (el) {return el instanceof HTMLElement;};
    } else if ((document.createElement("a")).constructor) {
        // We can access an element's constructor. So, this is not IE7
        var ElementConstructors = {}, nodeName;
        return function (el) {
            return el && typeof el.nodeName === "string" &&
                 (el instanceof ((nodeName = el.nodeName.toLowerCase()) in ElementConstructors 
                    ? ElementConstructors[nodeName] 
                    : (ElementConstructors[nodeName] = (document.createElement(nodeName)).constructor)))
        }
    } else {
        // Not that reliable, but we don't seem to have another choice. Probably IE7
        return function (el) {
            return typeof el === "object" && el.nodeType === 1 && typeof el.nodeName === "string";
        }
    }
})();
```

To improve performance I created a self-invoking function that tests the browser's capabilities only once and assigns the appropriate function accordingly.

The first test should work in most modern browsers and was already discussed here. It just tests if the element is an instance of `HTMLElement`. Very straightforward.

The second one is the most interesting one. This is its core-functionality:

```
return el instanceof (document.createElement(el.nodeName)).constructor
```

It tests whether el is an instance of the construcor it pretends to be. To do that, we need access to an element's contructor. That's why we're testing this in the if-Statement. IE7 for example fails this, because `(document.createElement("a")).constructor` is `undefined` in IE7.

The problem with this approach is that `document.createElement` is really not the fastest function and could easily slow down your application if you're testing a lot of elements with it. To solve this, I  decided to cache the constructors. The object `ElementConstructors` has nodeNames as keys with its corresponding constructors as values. If a constructor is already cached, it uses it from the cache, otherwise it creates the Element, caches its constructor for future access and then tests against it.

The third test is the unpleasant fallback. It tests whether el is an `object`, has a `nodeType` property set to `1` and a string as `nodeName`. This is not very reliable of course, yet the vast majority of users shouldn't even fall back so far.

This is the most reliable approach I came up with while still keeping performance as high as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Test if `obj` inherits from [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node).

```
if (obj instanceof Node){
    // obj is a DOM Object
}
```

Node is a basic [Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference) from which HTMLElement and Text inherit.

Answer (score 1):

For the ones using Angular:

```
angular.isElement
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isElement

Comment: More useful to include [Angular's code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/4daafd3dbe6a80d578f5a31df1bb99c77559543e/src/Angular.js#L712):  `function isElement(node) { return !!(node && (node.nodeName || (node.prop && node.attr && node.find))); }` Looks a little like [@finpingvin's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/384301/1028230). Note that it is determining "*if a reference is a DOM element (or wrapped jQuery element).*"

Answer (score 1):

This will work for almost any browser. (No distinction between elements and nodes here)

```
function dom_element_check(element){
    if (typeof element.nodeType !== 'undefined'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: first of all, you don't need to return true or return false, just return the if statement. Second, this will return true for {nodeType:1}

Comment: I tend to use overly verbose code (on this site) for the purpose of making the intention of the code clearer ;)

Answer (score 1):

differentiate a raw js object from a HTMLElement

```
function isDOM (x){
     return /HTML/.test( {}.toString.call(x) );
 }
```

use:

```
isDOM( {a:1} ) // false
isDOM( document.body ) // true
```

// OR

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "is",
    {
        value: function (x) {
            return {}.toString.call(this).indexOf(x) >= 0;
        }
    });
```

use:

`o={}; o.is("HTML") // false
 o=document.body; o.is("HTML") // true`

Comment: Interesting solution. It would be helpful to have a little more detail on why/how this works. What does the method compare in the end?

Comment: js thinks everithing as object , ojects extends by prototype, standard dom elements all share "toString" method that returns 4ex "HTMLDivElement"

Comment: Thanks for the details. I've just tested it myself and see `document.body.toString()` returns the string `"[object HTMLBodyElement]"`. If I get that right, another way to write isDOM could be `return -1 !== x.toString().indexOf("[object HTML")`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution to this task that checks the most basic important criterias of a DOM HTML element:

```
const isHTMLEl = o => typeof o === 'object' && !!o.tagName && o instanceof HTMLElement && !!o.nodeType;

const obj = document.createElement('iframe');
console.log( isHTMLEl(obj) ); // returns true
console.log( isHTMLEl([]) ); // return false
console.log( isHTMLEl('<div />') ); // returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a trick using jQuery

```
var obj = {};
var element = document.getElementById('myId'); // or simply $("#myId")

$(obj).html() == undefined // true
$(element).html() == undefined // false
```

so putting it in a function:

```
function isElement(obj){

   return (typeOf obj === 'object' && !($(obj).html() == undefined));

}
```

Comment: jQuery is internally doing `elem.nodeType === 1` so why not save the call overhead and the jQuery dependency and have your isElement function do that itself?

Comment: It's 2016, just say "no".

Answer (score 0):

Not to hammer on this or anything but for ES5-compliant browsers why not just:

```
function isDOM(e) {
  return (/HTML(?:.*)Element/).test(Object.prototype.toString.call(e).slice(8, -1));
}
```

Won't work on TextNodes and not sure about Shadow DOM or DocumentFragments etc. but *will* work on almost all HTML tag elements.

Answer (score 0):

A absolute right method, check target is a **real** html element
primary code:

```
    (function (scope) {
        if (!scope.window) {//May not run in window scope
            return;
        }
        var HTMLElement = window.HTMLElement || window.Element|| function() {};

        var tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var isChildOf = function(target, parent) {

            if (!target) {
                return false;
            }
            if (parent == null) {
                parent = document.body;
            }
            if (target === parent) {
                return true;
            }
            var newParent = target.parentNode || target.parentElement;
            if (!newParent) {
                return false;
            }
            return isChildOf(newParent, parent);
        }
        /**
         * The dom helper
         */
        var Dom = {
            /**
             * Detect if target element is child element of parent
             * @param {} target The target html node
             * @param {} parent The the parent to check
             * @returns {} 
             */
            IsChildOf: function (target, parent) {
                return isChildOf(target, parent);
            },
            /**
             * Detect target is html element
             * @param {} target The target to check
             * @returns {} True if target is html node
             */
            IsHtmlElement: function (target) {
                if (!X.Dom.IsHtmlNode(target)) {
                    return false;
                }
                return target.nodeType === 1;
            },
            /**
             * Detect target is html node
             * @param {} target The target to check
             * @returns {} True if target is html node
             */
            IsHtmlNode:function(target) {
                if (target instanceof HTMLElement) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (target != null) {
                    if (isChildOf(target, document.documentElement)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    try {
                        tempDiv.appendChild(target.cloneNode(false));
                        if (tempDiv.childNodes.length > 0) {
                            tempDiv.innerHTML = "";
                            return true;
                        }
                    } catch (e) {

                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        X.Dom = Dom;
    })(this);
```

[image: Test In IE 5]

Answer (score 0):

I have a special way to do this that has not yet been mentioned in the answers.

My solution is based on four tests. If the object passes all four, then it is an element:

1. The object is not null.
2. The object has a method called "appendChild".
3. The method "appendChild" was inherited from the **Node** class, and isn't just an imposter method (a user-created property with an identical name).
4. The object is of Node Type 1 (Element). Objects that inherit methods from the **Node** class are always Nodes, but not necessarily Elements.

Q: How do I check if a given property is inherited and isn't just an imposter?

A: A simple test to see if a method was truly inherited from **Node** is to first verify that the property has a type of "object" or "function". Next, convert the property to a string and check if the result contains the text "[Native Code]". If the result looks something like this:

```
function appendChild(){
[Native Code]
}
```

Then the method has been inherited from the Node object. See https://davidwalsh.name/detect-native-function

And finally, bringing all the tests together, the solution is:

```
function ObjectIsElement(obj) {
    var IsElem = true;
    if (obj == null) {
        IsElem = false;
    } else if (typeof(obj.appendChild) != "object" && typeof(obj.appendChild) != "function") {
        //IE8 and below returns "object" when getting the type of a function, IE9+ returns "function"
        IsElem = false;
    } else if ((obj.appendChild + '').replace(/[\r\n\t\b\f\v\xC2\xA0\x00-\x1F\x7F-\x9F ]/ig, '').search(/\{\[NativeCode]}$/i) == -1) {
        IsElem = false;
    } else if (obj.nodeType != 1) {
        IsElem = false;
    }
    return IsElem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each **DOMElement.constructor** returns *function HTML...Element()* or *[Object HTML...Element]* so...

```
function isDOM(getElem){
    if(getElem===null||typeof getElem==="undefined") return false;
    var c = getElem.constructor.toString();
    var html = c.search("HTML")!==-1;
    var element = c.search("Element")!==-1;
    return html&&element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(element instanceof $ && element.get(0) instanceof Element) || element instanceof Element
```

This will check for even if it is a jQuery or JavaScript DOM element

Answer (score 0):

The only way to guarentee you're checking an actual HTMLEement, and not just an object with the same properties as an HTML Element, is to determine if it inherits from Node, since its impossible to make a new Node() in JavaScript. (unless the native Node function is overwritten, but then you're out of luck). So:

```js
function isHTML(obj) {
    return obj instanceof Node;
}

console.log(
  isHTML(test),
  isHTML(ok),
  isHTML(p),
  isHTML(o),
  isHTML({
    constructor: {
      name: "HTML"
    }
  }),
  isHTML({
    __proto__: {
      __proto__: {
        __proto__: {
          __proto__: {
            constructor: {
              constructor: { 
                name: "Function"
                
              },
              name: "Node"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }),
)
```

```html
<div id=test></div>
<blockquote id="ok"></blockquote>
<p id=p></p>
<br id=o>
<!--think of anything else you want--!>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version. It has support for elements from iframe

```js
/**
 * @param {any} value
 * @param {any} view Optional. If the value is from an iframe, provide the iframe content window here.
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isHtmlElement(value, view) {
  if (value instanceof HTMLElement) return true
  if (view && value instanceof view.HTMLElement) return true

  return !!(
    value &&
    typeof value === 'object' &&
    value !== null &&
    value.nodeType === 1 &&
    typeof value.nodeName === 'string'
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for specific element type like my case i think this solution enough to detect if it valid audio element.

```
const elm = document.querySelector("#demo");
if (elm.nodeName && elm.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'audio'){
   alert(elm.nodeName);
}
```

> Said By google element.nodeName is a DOM Level 1 (1998) feature. It is
> fully supported in all browsers: Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari, Opera,
> IE. Yes, Yes ...
> so by logic if it has `nodeName` and it equal to audio it sure element and should work on all browser, if you need div or other element change the string note toLowerCase because `elm.nodeName` returns 'AUDIO'

Answer (score -1):

```
var isElement = function(e){
    try{
        // if e is an element attached to the DOM, we trace its lineage and use native functions to confirm its pedigree
        var a = [e], t, s, l = 0, h = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0], ht = document.getElementsByTagName('HTML')[0];
        while(l!=document.body&&l!=h&&l.parentNode) l = a[a.push(l.parentNode)-1];
        t = a[a.length-1];
        s = document.createElement('SCRIPT');   // safe to place anywhere and it won't show up
        while(a.length>1){  // assume the top node is an element for now...
            var p = a.pop(),n = a[a.length-1];
            p.insertBefore(s,n);
        }
        if(s.parentNode)s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
        if(t!=document.body&&t!=h&&t!=ht)
            // the top node is not attached to the document, so we don't have to worry about it resetting any dynamic media
            // test the top node
            document.createElement('DIV').appendChild(t).parentNode.removeChild(t);
        return e;
    }
    catch(e){}
    return null;
}
```

I tested this on Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera and IE9. I couldn't find a way to hack it.
In theory, it tests every ancestor of the proposed element, as well as the element itself, by inserting a script tag before it.
If its first ancestor traces back to a known element, such as `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>`, and it hasn't thrown an error along the way, we have an element.
If the first ancestor is not attached to the document, we create an element and attempt to place the proposed element inside of it, (and then remove it from the new element).
So it either traces back to a known element, successfully attaches to a known element or fails.
It returns the element or null if it is not an element.

Comment: You really should write code to be readable. Declaring variables ahead of use and leaving them with non-descriptive single character names is a massive warning sign to me and caused me to not bother to read your code. It's not more "optimized" for having been done that way.

Answer (score -1):

Most answers use some kind of duck typing, checking for example that the object has a `nodeType` property. But that's not enough, because non-nodes can also have node-like properties.

The other common approach is `instanceof`, which can produce false positives e.g. with `Object.create(Node)`, which is not a node despite inheriting node properties.

Moreover, both approaches above call internal essential methods, which can be problematic e.g. if the tested value is a proxy.

Instead, what I recommend is borrowing a node method and calling it on our object. The browser will check that the value is a node probably by looking at internal slots not customizable in proxies, so even they won't be able to interfere with our check.

```
function isNode(value) {
  try {
    Node.prototype.cloneNode.call(value, false);
    return true;
  } catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

You can also use property getters, if you prefer.

```js
function isNode(value) {
  try {
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Node.prototype,'nodeType').get.call(value);
    return true;
  } catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Similarly, if you want to test if a value is an element, you can use

```
function isElement(value) {
  try {
    Element.prototype.getAttribute.call(value, '');
    return true;
  } catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```
function isHTMLElement(value) {
  try {
    HTMLElement.prototype.click.call(value);
    return true;
  } catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: you isElement may return true for other objects with 'value' property, your isHTMLElement issues a click

Comment: @kofifus Can you provide an example which breaks `isElement`? And about the click, I thought it wasn't much harmful. `HTMLElement.prototype` does not contain many methods, but of course using a property getter (as shown in the hidden snippet) would be safer, but less clear.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using jQuery, try this

```
$('<div>').is('*') // true
$({tagName: 'a'}).is('*') // false
$({}).is('*') // false
$([]).is('*') // false
$(0).is('*') // false
$(NaN).is('*') // false
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this function:

```js
function isHTMLDOMElement(obj) {
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(-8) === 'Element]') {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(0, 12) === '[object HTML') {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1qazxsw2/wz7e0fvj/9/

Answer (score -2):

The easiest and cross-browser way to detect if an element is part of HTML DOM is as below:

```
function inHTMLDom(myelement){
    if(myelement.ownerDocument.documentElement.tagName.toLowerCase()=="html"){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

inHTMLDom(<your element>); // <your element>:element you are interested in checking.
```

tested in IE6,IE7,IE8,IE9,IE10,FF,Chrome,Safari,Opera.

Comment: If `myelement` isn't a DOM object, this will most likely crash.