# Check if variable is a valid node element

Tags: javascript, dom-node

How can I change a JS element to see if it is a node or an empty variable?

Comment: Related: [How do you check if a JavaScript Object is a DOM Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/384286/104380)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by an empty variable.

If you mean it hasn't had a value assigned, you can check for `undefined`

```
alert( someVariable !== "undefined" );
```

Or if you know it has a value, and need to see if it is an element, you could do something like this:

```
alert( someVariable && someVariable.nodeType );
```

Or if you need to verify that it is a type 1 element, you could do this:

```
alert( someVariable && someVariable.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE );
```

This eliminates text nodes, attribute nodes, comments, and [a bunch of others](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).

Comment: The nodeValue could be blank/empty/null, no? `!!(document.createElement('p')).nodeValue`

Comment: As long as it's not some other object with the property `nodeType`. Chances are slim, though.

Answer (score 10):

A node? A DOM element? it would have a `.nodeType` property.

Regarding `nodeValue` for the other answer, the nodeValue *can* be empty but a node will *always* have a `nodeType`.

Comment: for ```HTMLElement``` nodes, ```nodeType === 1```

Answer (score 8):

Using the HTML Element and taking a look at the Properties tab in Chrome Dev Tools
we can see the descendants:

***html->HTMLHtmlElement->HTMLElement->Element->Node->EventTarget->Object***

Now we do not want to check the first 2 no matter what, too many different possibilities
so that leave us with HTMLElement or Element. So what is the difference?

HTML, HEAD, SCRIPT, META, BODY, DIV, P and UL all have the same inheritance:

***HTMLElement->Element->Node->EventTarget->Object***

Now a few negative results from a typical document where:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     DocumentType->Node->EventTarget->Object
<!-- COMMENT -->    Comment->CharacterData->Node->EventTarget->Object
```

---

So Node is the common denominator, but the question is to how to check for a Valid DOM Node it is how to check for a valid DOM Node Element. So any object with HTMLElement to return true, otherwise return false.

Ok now using the Chrome Dev Tools lets look at the HTML Element:

```
$obj.nodeType;      //1     No help what so ever
$obj.nodeName;      //HTML  Gives use the tag names
$obj.nodeValue;     //null  Waste of DOM space
```

let's check the prototype or __proto?

```
$obj.prototype.nodeType;    //TypeError
$obj.prototype.nodeName;    //TypeError
$obj.prototype.nodeValue;   //TypeError

$obj.__proto__.nodeType;    //undefined
$obj.__proto__.nodeName;    //undefined
$obj.__proto__.nodeValue;   //undefined
```

Ok so using node is dead to use. Lets move to the constructor.

```
$obj.constructor.name       
//"HTMLHtmlElement"     promising...

$obj.constructor.__proto__.prototype.toString()
//[object Object]

$obj.constructor.__proto__.constructor.name
Function

$obj.constructor.__proto__.prototype.constructor.name
HTMLElement
//BINGO
```

Now lets wrap in in a nice clean efficient utility function.

```
//readable version
isElement=function($obj){
    try {
        return ($obj.constructor.__proto__.prototype.constructor.name)?true:false;
    }catch(e){
        return false;
    }
}

/**
     * PRODUCTION
 * Return true if object parameter is a DOM Element and false otherwise.
 *
 * @param {object} Object to test
 * @return {boolean}
 */
isElement=function(a){try{return a.constructor.__proto__.prototype.constructor.name?!0:!1}catch(b){return!1}};
```

Tests:

```
$html=get('html')[0];           //[<html data-role=​"webpage" data-theme=​"dark" data-require=​"fa" data-hello=​"world">​…​</html>​]
isElement($html);               //"HTMLElement"
isElement($html.dataset);       //false
isElement($html.firstChild);    //"HTMLElement"
isElement($html.textContent);   //false

$tail=gei('tail');              //<tail id=​"tail">​…​</tail>​
isElement($tail);               //"HTMLElement"

isElement(get('title')[0]);     //"HTMLElement"
```

Comment: meder points out that there is always a nodeType and that is correct. That was the first thing I checked and the value is 1. The standard defined nodeType 1 as "Element Represents an element Element, Text, Comment, ProcessingInstruction, CDATASection, EntityReference". The question was for 'Element' not Text, Comment, etc. So my isElement() function is the correct way? or am I wrong?

Comment: your extensive research impressed me but your conclusion is not implemented in your ```isElement()``` function. it should check for ```$obj.constructor.__proto__.prototype.constructor.name === 'HTMLElement'```, as other node types' constructors have a name, too. thank you very much for your solution, and the challenge to check.