# How to check if a variable is a node?

Tags: javascript, nodes, typechecking, dom-node

I want to know if the variable `myVar` is a node.

I could check `myVar.nodeType`, but then I could be fooled by `{nodeType:1}`

Then, I wonder if I can do something like

```
myVar instanceof Node
```

**Edit**

Funny, it seems that there is a `Node` constructor, so `instanceof Node` works, indeed!

I should have tried if my guess worked before asking...

---

Please don't mark my question as a duplicate of [Check if variable is a valid node element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781096/check-if-variable-is-a-valid-node-element), because this other question assumes that `myVar` is a node or is empty. But my question doesn't assume anything.

Comment: What's the problem with `myVar.nodeType === 1`?

Comment: What browser support do you need to achieve? Your presented code will fail in IE<=8.

Comment: @kol As I said, I could be fooled by `{nodeType:1}`: `({nodeType:1}).nodeType !== void(0)` returns `true` but `{nodeType:1}` isn't a node

Comment: Why the downvote? When finally I reach a pretty number of reputation, I always receive a downvote :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `window.document instanceof Node` in different browsers. It returns `true` in IE11, GC30, FF24 and Opera17 so it should work for other `Node`s, too.

In older browsers like IE8, the `Node` interface is `undefined`. I tested a couple of [interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference) like `HTMLDivElement` for `div` nodes, but these are too specific, so one would have to `||` them into a very long logical expression. The most general interface that works in IE8 is `Element`: `window.document.body` and its child nodes are instances of `Element`. Interestingly, `window.document` is not an `Element` (it's an `HTMLDocument`).

Comment: Haha, I should have tried if my guess worked, I didn't expect it!

Comment: @Oriol just note that `Node` is not actually a constructor, but rather an exposed DOM interface ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference)). Last time I checked, there's no standard for whether they should be exposed or not, hence you should check if it works in the browsers you support.