# jquery: test whether input variable is dom element

Tags: jquery, dom

I would like to write a jquery function that accepts either a dom element or its id as input:

```
function myfunction(myinput){
 // pseudocode:
 // if (myinput is dom element){
 //   var myID = $(myinput).attr('id');
 // } else {
 //   var myID = myinput;
 // }

 // Do stuff with myID ...

}
```

Question:  How can I tell whether myinput is a dom element???

Comment: This has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384286/javascript-isdom-how-do-you-check-if-a-javascript-object-is-a-dom-object

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's easier to do the check the other way around - check if it's a string if so use it to get an ID else treat it as a DOM node/element and handle it as if it was one.

```
function myfunction(myinput) {

    var myId;

    if (typeof myinput == 'string'){
        myId = myinput;
    } else {
        myId = myinput.id; // myinput.id is enough
    }

    // do something

}
```

or if you really want to check against if it's HTMLElement then every DOM html element extends HTMLElement abstract interface. [Check MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/htmlelement) for more info on HTMLElement.

```
    ...

    if (myinput instanceof HTMLElement){
        myId = myinput.id; // myinput.id is enough
    } else {
        myId = myinput;
    }

    ...
```

In the end it won't really matter... your call!

Tom

Comment: HTMLElement wasn't working for me in some browser (probably IE8) so now I'm checking for `nodeType`

Comment: You could do ```$(myinput).length > 0``` to see if element exists in the DOM.

Answer (score 6):

You would implement your function like this:

```
function myfunction(myinput){

 if (myinput.nodeType){
    var myID = $(myinput).attr('id');
 } else {
    var myID = myinput;
 }

 // Do stuff with myID ...
```

}

More information about [nodeType](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/nodetype.shtml).

Comment: +1 for this solution.  jQuery code uses this in its isPlainObject function to exclude DOM nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if a nice ternary would work, something like this

```
var myID = $(myInput).attr('id') ? $(myInput).attr('id') : myInput;
```

Answer (score -2):

`if( myinput instanceof domElement ) alert("Yes");`

Comment: Nope, there's no such class as `domElement`.

Comment: What you mean is `Element` or `Node` ;)