# About HTML5's new feature placeholder on Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, placeholder, fallback

On Firefox:

`console.log(document.createElement('input').placeholder === ''); // true`

`console.log(document.createElement('input').hasOwnProperty('placeholder')); // false`

I think the 2nd line codes should return `true` just like what you can see on Chrome. But I get `false`. Why?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325205/how-come-there-is-a-difference-between-chrome-and-firefox-here

Comment: also this is not about HTML5, it's the same just with any other attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec defines the JS property as being on the prototype, not on the object itself.  Chrome gets this wrong for all DOM properties; it's a longstanding bug in Chrome.

Comment: I think your answer is right! Thank you! This should be a WebKit's bug relevant its implementation to DOM. Safari also has this bug.