# Cross browser solution for checking if a Javascript object is an html element

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser, yui

The following code work in FF but not IE8:

```
var j = "test";
alert(j instanceof HTMLElement);
```

I don't think IE uses the HTMLElement object. Is there a safe way to do this check in IE? Perhaps there is a YUI solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript isDOM -- How do you check if a Javascript Object is a DOM Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384286/javascript-isdom-how-do-you-check-if-a-javascript-object-is-a-dom-object)

Comment: @Roatin nope, an element can be in the DOM without being an HTML element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use to check the nodeType property, it should be 1 for all HTML element objects.

I used it in my crossbrowser library before I switched to jQuery.

text has a nodeType of 3 and any custom objects probably won't have a nodeType property at all.

Comment: http://help.dottoro.com/ljkadgoo.php I think you got it backwards? Text is type 3, and Element is type 1?

Comment: Someone needs to correct this answer, it is backwards :)  text node: 3, element node: 1, comment node: 8, etc etc.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType

Comment: Fixed the numbers, sorry for getting them backwards and not noticing the first comment notice emails :/

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the jQuery source code (not the minified one ffs!), you'll see they make use of `nodeType` a lot.