# JavaScript: distinguish DOM element objects and Event objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript isDOM — How do you check if a Javascript Object is a DOM Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384286/javascript-isdom-how-do-you-check-if-a-javascript-object-is-a-dom-object)

I have the following simple function:

```
function do_smth(el){

    if(typeof el != 'object'){
        el = this
    }
    var val = $.trim(el.value)

     /**** some code here ****/

}
```

Sometimes it is binded to an element as an event

1)

```
element.onclick = do_smth
```

and sometimes it is used the following way

2)

```
do_smth(element)
```

both ways this should work good...

The problem is that I get the `el` as `Event` object in the first case, even if there are no arguments passed. 
So `typeof el != 'object'` does not work as expected.

How can I distinguish DOM element or Event?

Comment: You should use the function in a consistent way imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function do_smth(el){
    el = el.nodeType == 1 ? el : this;
    var val = $.trim(el.value)
}
```

Comment: `el` will be the event object when used as event handler.

Comment: no, `el` is always defined, it can be an event

Comment: right, I misunderstood the question. Updated...

Answer (score 1):

To distingusih a DOM element do

```
if(el.nodeType)
```

Comment: Well if you certain it is an element and not a document or text node then you could do `el.nodeType===1` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType

Comment: nodeType returns a 1 for element nodes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType

Comment: Yeah, but event objects don't have a nodeType at all, so just querying if the value is existent should be fine.  It would be more safe to do `if(el.nodeType===1)` though

Comment: Yup well there is a slight bug in [IE5](http://quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t21)