# how to know if an object is an Html document using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-8

I'm passing an object say, `obj`, to a function. `obj` could possibly of ***any type*** - *(TemplatedHelper, AlertMessage, PartialViews, HTMLDocument, etc.)* I want to know if `obj` is an HTML Document. What are the possible ways to achieve it?

I have tried using

```
    var containerCount = $(obj).length;
      for (var ctr = 0; ctr < containerCount; ctr++) {
        var containerTagName = $(obj)[ctr].tagName;
        alert(containerTagName); // to know all detected tagNames
                                 // this returns LINK, SCRIPT, DIV, INPUT, etc..                   
        if ((containerTagName == "TITLE") || (containerTagName == "HTML")) {
          var isHTML = true;
          break;
        }
      }
```

with the preceding code, Chrome only detects the `title` tag, but IE8 doesn't detect `html`, `head`, and `title` tags. While these fragment codes don't work in IE8 too:

```
    alert($(obj).has('title')); // or 'html' as element parameter, returns [object Object]
    alert($(obj).find('title')); // or 'html' as element parameter, returns [object Object]
    if ($(obj)[ctr].parent())  
      alert($(obj)[ctr].parent().get(0).tagName); // returns undefined
```

Please share me your thoughts about it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: An HTML document doesn't necessarily have to have a title tag.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384286/javascript-isdom-how-do-you-check-if-a-javascript-object-is-a-dom-object) question and its answers.

Comment: @annonymously: `obj` may also be a *PartialView* and it must take a different function than *HTMLDocuments'*. How would it be?

Comment: Use `if (obj instanceof HTMLDocument)` to find out if `obj` is of type `HTMLDocument`. From what I understand, that's what you want.

Comment: @Brad: Yup. that's why I've included title tags in all of my HTML Documents ;) only `html`, `head`, and `title` tags make an HTML Document different from PartialViews or did I miss something?

Comment: @annonymously: YES! that's what I want :) but that returns *false*. :( is it possible to select an `html` or `head` tag?

Comment: Are you sure that `obj` *is* a `HTMLDocument`? If it's not then it will obviously return false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (obj instanceof HTMLDocument)
{
    // obj is a HTMLDocument
}
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == "[object HTMLDocument]")
{
    // obj is a HTMLDocument
}
```

Comment: *Microsoft JScript runtime error: Function expected* error is shown, but when I ignored the error, it returned `True`. What's wrong?

Comment: I don't know why the error is being thrown, but if it works, just ignore it.

Comment: The first 'if' is wrong for documents from other iframes. the second is more generic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$obj.is('html')
```

Comment: `obj` is not the tag but the html doc, but I got what you meant. I have to select first the `html` tag before using your answer. Do you have any idea on how to do it?