# How to tell if an object is $(document) inside a jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, object, document

```javascript
$.fn.foo = function() {
    console.log($(this));
};

$("#foo").foo();

$(document).foo();
```

How can I tell weather `$(this)` inside the function is `$(document)` or not?

---

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326889/how-to-know-if-an-object-is-an-html-document-using-javascript), people suggested

```javascript
1. if (obj instanceof HTMLDocument)

2. if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == "[object HTMLDocument]")

3. $obj.is('html')
```

but none of them works.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to prove, but the statement `$(this) == $(document)` returns `false`.

Comment: This won't work. Even `$(document) == $(document)` will result in false, as these are two different objects.

Comment: don't wrap them just use (this === document)

Comment: No, this won't work either: `this` is a jQuery object, `document` is an Element one.

Comment: no, `$(this)` is a jquery object, `this` is not

Comment: @DavidFregoli read here - `this` is a jQuery object http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Context

Comment: sorry didn't notice it's extending $. then just do this[0] == document

Comment: I don't get it why I got a down-vote for this question...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about simple...

```
if (this[0] === document)
```

... as `this` inside jQuery function corresponds to jQuery object (not HTML one). Even if this object is empty, `this[0]` is still a valid expression - it's just `undefined`.

An alternative is to use jQuery [**is**](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
if ($(this).is(document))
```

... as it accepts `DOMElement` as a param too.

Comment: +1 saw you had the right answer so I waited.. but `this` doesn't need to be wrapped if it's inside the jQuery function

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.foo = function() {
    console.log(this[0] == document);
};

$("#foo").foo();

$(document).foo();
```

Comment: maybe you should type faster next time. but thanks anyway. :)