# javascript null.valueAsNumber cannot convert to Object

Tags: javascript, adobe

I'm new to javascript, and am stumbling through it.  I am trying to use javascript to calculate a value based on three different values in the forms.  the problem is that the only output I get is:
[ Line: 00004 { (null) } ] : Null null.valueAsNumber cannot convert to Object

Here is the sample code:

```
function YellowPay(aNames) {
    var MaxYellow, YellowMil, YellowGallons, Mil, PayGals;
    MaxYellow = this.getField(aNames[1]).valueAsNumber;
    YellowMil = this.getField(aNames[2]).valueAsNumber;
    YellowGallons = this.getField(aNames[3]).valueAsNumber;
    Mil = Math.round(YellowMil * 100) / 100;
    PayGals = "";
    if (Mil >= 25) {
        PayGals = MaxYellow;
    } else if (Mil >= 20) {
        PayGals = YellowGallons;
    } else if (Mil >= 18) {
        PayGals = YellowGallons * 0.75;
    } else if (Mil >= 17) {
        PayGals = YellowGallons * 0.5;
    } else {
        PayGals = 0;
    }
    YellowPay = PayGals;
}
event.value = YellowPay(["MaxYellow", "YellowMil", "YellowGallons"]);
```

Comment: Where is defined `getField` and what is `valueAsNumber`?

Comment: @Jonathan: that's a DOM property that applies ToNumber() to `value`.

Comment: So I guess the problem is in `getField`, make sure you return a DOM object

Comment: @Jonathan:  Is there a way to verify if an object is a DOM object?

Comment: @zanestoy check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384286/javascript-isdom-how-do-you-check-if-a-javascript-object-is-a-dom-object)