# How to differentiate between DOM object and JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I tried to find out which is a dom object or which is a javascript object

```
var domObj =document.getElementById('lga');

typeof domObj

"object"

var jsObj = {name:"BP"}

typeof jsObj

"object"
```

Then how do I identify which is a dom object or js object.

Comment: DOM objects *are* javascript objects if accessing them via javascript.

Comment: so what you really want to know is "is some object a DOM object or not a DOM object?"

Comment: jQuery only does `else if ( selector.nodeType )`. Of course you will get false positives if a normal object has such a property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
domObj instanceof HTMLElement; // true
```

It will be false for

```
jsObj instanceof HTMLElement; // false
```

---

In an `if` it would look like this

```
if (domObj instanceof HTMLElement) {
  // ...
}
else {
  // ...
}
```

---

You can learn more about your objects by inspecting their `constructor` property

```
document.body.constructor; // function HTMLBodyElement() { [native code] }
```

Comment: Good idea.  Instead of HTMLElement, you could compare to Node if you were also interested in TextNodes, CommentNodes, etc.

Comment: domObj instanceof HTMLElement;

this works fine in Chrome but not in IE8,

domObj instanceof Object;

This returns true in Chrome but false in IE8.

Is there any specific way to do it crossbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be of help
[Javascript isDOM - How do you check if a Javascript Object is a DOM Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384380/2115788)

This gives a cross-browser way to handle the requirement, at the same time explaining the underlying implementation of common browsers.
I think this should answer your question on how to identify an `object` of type `HTMLElement`.