# How to find out DOM element node type derived from HTMLElement?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to find the element type of a tag and even tried looking in the spec here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#elements-in-the-dom

I thought I can do this `document.createElement('button').__proto__` to get HTMLButtonElement, but not very clear that is what it is. Is there a way to find this out? Preferably something I can write out to the console or maybe there is a better reference that lists them all more clearly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript isDOM -- How do you check if a Javascript Object is a DOM Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384286/javascript-isdom-how-do-you-check-if-a-javascript-object-is-a-dom-object)

Comment: NOT a duplicate. Question is how to find out the DOM type, not to check against other DOM types. I don't know the DOM types ahead of time and want to extract it, not compare it to another.

Comment: `window.toString.call( element )`? The possible classes [are here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API)

Comment: @megawac, that actually works! Great find!! Pls post an answer and I will mark it correct. You can also do this: document.createElement('img').toString()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `toString` on an element should return a string of the elements super class as I mentioned in comments (and is actually quite a common technique used in libraries eg `toString.call([]) === "[object Array]")` for array checking.

Anyway getting on with it, you can get the elements super class via `toString` or `element.constructor` call

```
var element = document.createElement("span");
var toString = window.toString;

toString.call(element) === "[object HTMLSpanElement]"; //true
element.constructor === HTMLSpanElement; //true
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the property '`nodeType`'. If your element is '`x`', then '`x.nodeType`' will give you type of '`x`'.

If you want the name of the node's tag, then use the 'nodeName' property.

Comment: Incorrect. The `nodeType` property returns a numeric code representing the type of node (element, text, comment, etc). See [Node.nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType) for more info.

Comment: The question was asked about type. Even regarding your comment, I have added to answer.