# Remove DOM elements from variable object for posting it to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got javascript object that holds a few depths of data.  One of the depths has literal dom elements attached.  I need to post this object (I'm using jQuery's post func), but I get an illegal invocation because of those dom elements. Is there a quick way to remove those dom elements without having to loop through the object / array?

Comment: No, not really. If there was, it'd have to just hide the looping/recursion in a function.

Comment: How do you send it? As XML? JSON? Do you actually want to send the DOM elements?

Comment: @Bergi sending as JSON.  I don't want the dom elements sen, I don't think you even can.

Comment: I think you can use ```.filter()```, but in the end; there will still be an internal loop

Comment: @adirohan filter won't work for this case.

Comment: yes, you are right , so ```for in``` loop would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. When serializing the Objects to JSON, you can use a [`replacer` predicate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to remove or modify arbitrary data. In your case it would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "…",
    data: JSON.stringify(data, function(p,o) {
        if (o instanceof HTMLElement) return null;
        return o;
    }),
    …
});
```

For more thorough ways of detecting DOM elements see [JavaScript isDOM -- How do you check if a JavaScript Object is a DOM Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/384286/1048572).

Comment: I see what you did there!  This doesn't work though, it returns an empty string.

Comment: Right, I forgot the `propertyName` argument of the replacer. Works now :-)