# Free jqGrid 4.8.0 - getCell not working after last update

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have just download the latest and greatest sources from the Free-jqGrid GIT.

Just replacing the old version I had yield an error, that after a debug found out to be an issue with the getCell function.

The following:

celValue = $('#'+gridName).jqGrid ('getCell', rowid, 'id');

ending up with **celValue =""**, instead of the actual value.  I was clicking on the second line, the rowid came back as 'mainSession2', the gridName came back as 'mainSession' which is all good, yet the output that is expected is "2", and came back empty.

In a test I did on last Tuesday (If i'm not mistaken), with the sources I download back then, there was no issue.

Thanks,

Comment: I made many changes last days. Could you verify that the problem still exist now? If it's exist, please post small demo which can be used to reproduce the problem. If I try just use `getCell` after the grid is created I can't see any problem.

Comment: Thanks,  I was using a download from 60 minutes ago, so yep, it's the latest.  I'm using idPrefix in my grids, so since it takes part in this function, this might be the reason you couldn't re-create?  I'll try to upload.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mrfvsyc2/11/

Comment: Above is the uploaded example.  look for the line  alert('rowid is: "' + rowid + '", Value is "' + celValue + '"');  the celValue is always undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report!

I made today the changes to fix problems in IE8, reported in [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/77). I used [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384380/315935) as the basis for the changes, but I tested my changes only in IE10 and not in Chrome. The problem is that `typeof HTMLElement` is `"function"` in Chrome and `"object"` in IE.

It's very good that there are people who uses the current sources from GitHub. It helps to fix the problem very quickly. I posted [the fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/da165aff68e30e159eea54b6aaf8a23ca840d7a6) which should solve the problem. The demo which you posted works now. Please refresh the sources which you used.