# Is it reliable to only check if an argument is a node before using querySelectorAll on it?

Tags: javascript, dom, selectors-api

Currently, I see that the method `querySelectorAll` is found on the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which is a `node` and not an element, and found on [HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).

I am working with a function that accepts as the first parameter, either a node, element, or a selector that then finds an element. I need to check type of node, because the function should work is `document` is passed in.

```
function queryElement(elementOrSelector) {
    if (!isNode(elementOrSelector)) {
        elementOrSelector = document.querySelector(elementOrSelector);
    }
    // This next line is the line I worry about
    var possibleElements = elementOrSelector.querySelector('[test]');
    ...
}

function isNode(o) {
    return (
        typeof Node === "object" ? o instanceof Node :
        o && typeof o === "object" && typeof o.nodeType === "number" && typeof o.nodeName === "string"
    );
}
```

This allows me to pass in the following:

```
queryElement(document);
// or
queryElement(document.querySelector('select'));
```

and they will all work. But right now, I am only checking to see if they are of type `node` when technically, the `querySelectorAll` method only exists on the `document`, and the HTML `Element` prototype. I believe that `Element` inherits from `Node` so that is why most of it is working. But if I only ever check type of `node`, will I run into problems? Is there a particular `node` that is also not an `Element` that will not have `querySelectorAll` available to it?

Comment: you could do `if (!'querySelector' in elementOrSelector)` - this is called "feature detection"

Comment: `typeof Node` should return `"function"`, not `"object"`. Are you testing some IE oddity?

Comment: @JaromandaX, that is an awesome suggestion, wishing I had thought that one through sooner.

Comment: @Oriol, based on some of the oddities talked about in the [accepted answer in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384286/javascript-isdom-how-do-you-check-if-a-javascript-object-is-a-dom-object), I went with that solution for detecting if type of node.

Comment: @KevBot That answer complains about `Node` being a function "instead of the expected object". That makes no sense in ES5. I'm sure the code does not behave like the answerer expected, and even if it did, it's not a reliable check. The reason is probably that the answer is so old that precedes ES5, and maybe some old IE returned "object".

Comment: @Oriol, that's great information. I'm reading through a couple of different sources on the Node type/instance now. That point has saved me from a couple pitfalls already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a particular node that is also not an `Element` that will not
>   have `querySelectorAll` available to it?

Yes. For example:

- Attribute nodes (removed in DOM4)
- Doctypes
- Text nodes
- Comment nodes

I think the only reliable way to check if something is a node is attempting to use it as a node, and see if it throws an error.

However, checking if the object has a `querySelector` property (and maybe that its value is a function) is probably enough.