# Inserting an Image into a Table

Tags: javascript, image, html-table

I have a table where I am inserting data into the table from a query. Because I am treating every key and pair as a text when I insert the image it is returning **[object HTMLImageElement]**. Because I am converting it to text after the fact it is not rendering properly. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
            if (condition) == 1) {
               var image = document.createElement("img");
               image.src = "source1.png";

             } else if (condition) == 0 ) {
               var image = document.createElement("img");
               image.src = "source2.png";
             }

             let Table = [

               {'First Text Item': 'Text Result'),
               'Second Text Item': 'Text Result',
               'Third Text Item': 'Text Result',
               'Fourth Text Item': 'Text Result',
               'Fifth Text Item': 'Text Result',
               'Image': image},

             ];

             function generateTable(table, data) {
               for (let element of data) {
                 let row = table.insertRow();
                 for (key in element) {
                   let cell = row.insertCell();
                   let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
                   cell.appendChild(text);
                 }
               }
             }
             generateTable(table, Table);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your problem is with `let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);`

You need to check if the attribute is a DOM component:

- if it is an Image DOM element - add it directly
- if not `let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);`

You can see this answer on how to detect DOM elements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/384380/2938073

You can get DOM type by using `Element.tagName` ([see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName))

Comment: I can get the images to show up by removing ```let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);``` and replacing ```cell.appendChild(text)``` with  ```cell.innerHTML = element[key].outerHTML;``` but then every other text element is undefined